# Programação visual QT C++

Tags: qt, qtgui

Estou com um trabalho para a faculdade e gostaria da ajuda dos veteranos em um ponto.

quero criar uma bloco com inputText, checkbox e combobox imagem de referencial.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando por exemplo o QGridLayout é facil criar, mas ainda preciso ligar dois desses por um pathCubic segue imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então qual seria a melhor forma ? para unir os dois ?
ou crio tudo com QGraphics ? mais ai eu não conseguiria criar os combobox e outros ?

gratos a todos que ajudarem :)

Comment: Isso não me parece Qt... me parece o editor visual de uma engine de jogos, como Unreal ou Unity. Não enchergo absolutamente nada do que disse nas imagens no post. Por favor, verifique se as imagens estão corretas.

Comment: Poderia ser o caso de você implementar um sistema hibrido, desenhando as splines no PaintEvent, e pondo widgets normais na tela usando diretamente as coordenadas, sem layout. Aliás, é um dos raros casos em que eu recomendo usar coordenadas no lugar de layouts em Qt. QGraphics talvez possa te atender também, nada impede de usar widgets conjuntamente.

Comment: Estas são penas imagem para tomar base no que eu quero fazer Vinicius mas vlw pela ajuda.

Bacco: agora você sim entendeu ^^ pensei em fazer isso mesmo estou implementando isso vlww quando pronto vou dar um feedback